# printing requests.get is not showing a HTML output

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a simple [yahoofinance page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN), my code looks like this :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN"
headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I expected a HTML document to be printed, instead I am getting something that starts like this:

[image]

While debugging, I can clearly see that the response.code is 200 and that the soup contains the expected HTML documents:

[image]

Even without going through BeautifulSoup, and just using:

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN"
headers={'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

I am getting the same result.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong ?

I expected a HTML document but I am getting random numbers and letters

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment (operating system, python version)? I can't reproduce the behavior you've described using Python 3.12 (I get HTML output as expected).

Comment: Hi, I am running python 3.11 and Windows 10 64bit compiling on Pycharm. Compiling on VS code gave the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is actually working fine.

If you inspect the source of [that page](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN), there is an embedded javascript that contains a block of encoded text as the value of `root.App.main.context.dispatcher.stores`. That block looks very much like what you're showing in your question. There's around 1.5MB of data contained in that script.

That means that any attempt to print the source of that page is going to generate too much output to be useful, but it doesn't prevent you from using BeautifulSoup to perform queries on the page:

```
>>> res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN')
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
>>> x = soup.find('span', string='Previous Close')
>>> x.findParent().findNextSibling().text
'147.42'
```